# Show the unilateral forward shift is essentially normal

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras

Let $H$ be a complex, infinite dimensional, separable complex Hilbert space with orthonormal basis $(e_n)_n$.

Let $T$ be the unilateral forward shift with $Te_n= e_{n+1}$.

We say that $T \in \mathcal{B(H)}$ is essentially normal if the image $\pi(T)$ of $T$ under the canonical quotient map $\pi: \mathcal{B(H)} \rightarrow {\mathcal{B(H)}}/{\mathcal{K(H)}}$ in a sense that $\pi(T)\pi(T^*)= \pi(T^*)\pi(T)$

Show that $T$ is essentially normal.

What I've tried:

Since the quotient map is linear, I want to show that

$\pi(T)\pi(T^*) - \pi(T^*) \pi(T)=\pi(TT^*) - \pi(T^*T)= \pi(TT^*- T^*T)=0$

But not I'm confused because isn't that equivalent to showing that $T$ is normal?
i.e. $TT^* - T^*T = 0$.

Also, I'm not sure how to find $TT^* - T^*T$.

Any help will be appreciated!

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What is $\mathcal{K}(\mathcal{H})$?

Comment: $\mathcal{B(H)} / \mathcal{K(H)}$ is a banach algebra, the Calkin Algebra. $\mathcal{K(H)}$ is the set of compact operators, and it is a closed, two-sided ideal of $\mathcal{B(H)}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints: since $\langle T^*e_n,e_m\rangle=\delta_{n(m+1)}$ show that $\langle T^*e_n,x\rangle=\langle e_{n-1},x\rangle$ and therefore that $T^*e_n=e_{n-1}$. Then, $T^*T-TT^*=I-TT^*.$ which you can show by direct calculation, to be projection on the rank one subspace spanned by $e_0.$

Comment: I got that $\langle T^* e_n, x \rangle = \langle e_n, \sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} x_n e_{n+1} \rangle$. Can I say that $\langle e_n, \sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} x_n e_{n+1} \rangle = \langle e_{n-1},  \sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} x_n e_{n} \rangle$? Is this a valid operation?

Comment: Sorry I still don't see how $T^*T-TT^* = I- TT^*$ will imply that $\pi(T^*T-TT^*)=0$. Thank you!

Comment: The projection is compact because its range has finite dimension, so .....

Answer (score 1):

$\pi$ is not injective. The equality $\pi(T^*T-TT^*)=0$ does not tell you that $T^*T-TT^*=0$, but that $T^*T-TT^*$ is compact.

Comment: But we can say that $T^*T-TT^*=0$ implies  $\pi(T^*T-TT^*)=0$. Is that right?  I am a bit confused because I got $(T^*T-TT^*)e_n= T^*T e_n  -TT^*e_n = 0$ ,since $T^*e_n = e_{n-1}$. Then are we done showing that $T$ is essentially normal? I feel like I've made a mistake somewhere...

Comment: Every linear function maps zero to zero, so that's not really relevant. And yes, you made a mistake: $(T^*T-TT^*)e_1=e_1$.

Comment: So do we have $(T^*T-TT^*)e_1 = e_1$ and $(T^*T-TT^*)e_n = e_n$ for $n>1$?  Also, to show $\pi(T^*T - TT^* )=0$, what is our goal for $(T^*T - TT^* )$? Do we have to show that $(T^*T - TT^* )$ is compact? Thank you for your help!

Comment: No, as you had already said, $(T^*T-TT^*)e_n=0$ for $n>1$. And yes, you want to show that $T^*T-TT^*$ is compact, as this is equivalent with $\pi(T^*T-TT^*)=0$.